# Shooting down a raycast that decides what landing animation plays

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

As the title says, I'm trying to create a mechanic that decides what landing the third person controller should play. The player has a "HardLanding" and a "NormalLanding" animation. At first I tried achieving this with a timer, but this doesn't deliver the expected behaviour (When the player jumps forward it also plays the HardLanding animation, which is not what should happen). I'm using a character controller component, so there is no rigidbody or collider (Only the CharacterController and the script).

I have already setup a void that raycasts downwards, and this is currently being done when the player is not grounded. The problem is that the groundCheck is being updated every frame because it's in the update function. This means this ray is sent out every frame and gives different values. I think this ray should either only shoot once, so there is a single value that determines the height of the player, or that the ray that currently shoots out as long as the player is not grounded should be checked on its highest value and than I can do something like. if (rayheight number is higher than x) { play HardLanding} else {play NormalLanding}. The landing animation should start playing when the player is grounded again obviously.

Here is what I have gotton so far, which doens't work yet:

```
void CheckFallingDistance()
{
    RaycastHit hitFall;
    Vector3 bottom = controller.transform.position - new Vector3(0, controller.height / 2, 0);

    if (Physics.Raycast(bottom, dirDown, out hitFall))
    {
        rayDistance = hitFall.distance;
    }

    Debug.DrawRay(bottom, dirDown * hitFall.distance, Color.cyan, 10f);
}
```

Below you can see my current groundcheck which still contains the timer to decide which landing animation should play. The timer part should be replaced with the raycast check for falling height.

```
if (GroundCheck())
    {
        velocityY = 0;
        if (airTime > airTimeHandler)
        {
            //Debug.Log("Hard landing");
            anim.SetBool("hardLanding", true);
            anim.SetBool("onAir", false);
            anim.SetBool("onAirIdle", false);
        }
        else
        {
            //Debug.Log("Normal landing");
            anim.SetBool("hardLanding", false);
            anim.SetBool("onAir", false);
            anim.SetBool("onAirIdle", false);
        }
        airTime = 0f;
    }
    else
    {
        CheckFallingDistance();
        if (animationSpeedPercent < 0.51f)
        {
            anim.SetBool("onAirIdle", true);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("onAir", true);
        }
        anim.SetBool("hardLanding", false);
        airTime += Time.deltaTime;
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually I decided to ditch the raycast part and went for a check of the Y velocity of the charactercontroller component.

Answer (score 0):

You know your player's absolute position (y component), what remains is finding out the gound height at this point. If your floor is at y=0 than this is trivial, but since you mention raycasting I am assuming its not. 
I would assume  you only need to measure height at the highest point, you can launch a Coroutine when you leave the ground (its best to avoid Update()), and check for vertical position in each frame within that coroutine. At the beggining phase of the jump the position will increase, but at some point current position will become lower than the position in the last frame. This is the frame when you shoot your raycast, and make a decision as to which animation you play. You can end your coroutine at this point (this is unless your ground is terribly uneven).

You could also measure player velocity before landing and decide based on that

Comment: I think I get what you mean. The heightCheck is going to be within a coroutine, and the coroutine is going to be within the ground check. The coroutine checks all the y values, and when it's on the highest value it shoots down the ray to check the highest point. The problem is though, I have no idea how to code that. Maybe you can elaborate a bit more on the solution?